# Move right column below the fixed sidebar on the left when resizing browser

Tags: html, css, flexbox, responsive

I have a fixed sidebar on the left and a right column with a couple of cards that are vertically aligned. How do I make the right column fall under the sidebar upon resize, so that the sidebar becomes a top bar with around 50% of the height of the viewport?

I want to maintain the ratio of the current spacing and for the content to remain vertically aligned. Also trying to make the sidebar no longer be fixed when it's resized.

Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/snacks00/wLd67f1t/

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.sidebar {
  width: 40%;
  height: 100vh;
  text-align: center;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05), 2px 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.right-column {
  width: 60%;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: 40%;
  background-color: #F9F9F9;
}

.card {
  display: flex;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 10%;
  margin: 10%;
  background-color: #fff;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px #d3d3d3;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px #d3d3d3;
}

@media (max-height: 45em) {
  .sidebar {
  height:500px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: fixed;
    float: left;
    }


}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>


  <div class="sidebar">
    <h2>Sidebar</h2>
  </div>

 <div class="right-column">
    <div class="content" id="1">
      <div class="card">
      <p>Card number 1</p> </div> 
    </div>

    <div class="content" id="2">
      <div class="card">
      <p>Card number 2</p> </div> 
    </div>

      <div class="content" id="3">
      <div class="card">
      <p>Card number 3</p> </div> 
    </div>

    <div class="content" id="4">
      <div class="card">
      <p>Card number 4</p> </div> 
    </div>
  </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should first consider setting the **position** of the sidebar to *static* in your media query. Otherwise, it will go over the cards.

For the cards to go below the sidebar in mobile mode, I would put everything in a flexbox container with the **flex-wrap** property set to *wrap*:  it will allow the items to wrap if there's not enough space in a single line.

[image]

You could also use the [bootstrap grid system](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/). Hope that helps!